# Retrieve an object within an NSArray / NSDictionary hierarchy based on other objects within it

Tags: iphone, nsarray, nsdictionary

Sorry about the weird title... all will be explained.

Basically I have an array/dictionary structure like this in my app:

```
NSArray {

    NSDictionary {
        (NSString *)id;
        (NSDictionary *)dictionary;
    }

    NSDictionary {
        (NSString *)id;
        (NSDictionary *)dictionary;
    }

    NSDictionary {
        (NSString *)id;
        (NSDictionary *)dictionary;
    }

    etc...

}
```

Hope that's easy to work out...

Now I have an `(NSString *)id` and I want to get the `(NSDictionary *)dictionary` which corresponds to it.

Is there any way that I can do this?

Thank you

Tom

Answer (score 2, accepted):

Try something like this

```
for (NSDictionary *dict in dictArray) {
    if ([[dict objectForKey:@"id"] isEqualToString:targetID]){
        return [dict objectForKey:@"dictionary"];
    }
}
```

I have not compiled the code(don't have mac near me), but I think you got the idea. The basic idea is to loop through the array and compare query string. But if you have many items then this linear search might be time consuming.

Comment: is this the best way then? there's no "simpler" way at all?

Comment: As you have an array of dictionary, no better way is coming to my mind right now. May be other members can suggest better ways.

Answer (score 2):

If the `ids` are unique, I'd use `NSDictionary` as my top level object instead of the NSArray. That way you can just do: `[dict objectForKey:stringID]`

`NSArray` doesn't really make sense here unless you are using it as a tables datasource.

Comment: Hmm, that is a good idea, but I have built all my code around this concept now. There was probably a very good reason why I didn't do it that way round to start off with. I can't quite remember what that is though.

Comment: Comments are your friend ;) Yeah, I don't recommend changing your codebase. But something to keep in mind for the future. The only time I wrap within an `NSArray` is when I need it for a `UITableView`.